# How to inject ngx bootstrap modules into child module - Angular 4

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, angular5

My application folder structure is like below:

```
>app
  app.module.ts
  app.routing.ts
>>auth
  login.component
  auth.module.ts
  atuh.routing.module.ts
```

Now I would like to use the `ngx-intl-input` module which has dependency on `ngx-bootstrap`. I would like to include `intl-input` in the login component.

So if I import `ngx-bootsrap` in `auth.module`...

auth.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { AuthRoutingModule } from './auth-routing.module';
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { NgxIntlTelInputModule } from 'ngx-intl-tel-input';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AuthRoutingModule,
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    NgxIntlTelInputModule
  ],
  declarations: [LoginComponent]
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: 
StaticInjectorError[ComponentLoaderFactory]: 
  StaticInjectorError[ComponentLoaderFactory]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ComponentLoaderFactory!
Error: StaticInjectorError[ComponentLoaderFactory]: 
  StaticInjectorError[ComponentLoaderFactory]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ComponentLoaderFactory!
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js:993)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1281)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1223)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1094)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1281)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1223)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1094)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10878)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:12110)
    at resolveDep (core.js:12608)
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js:993)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1281)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1223)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1094)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1281)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1223)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1094)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10878)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:12110)
    at resolveDep (core.js:12608)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:824)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:795)
    at eval (zone.js:873)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4744)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:602)
    at <anonymous>
```

I tried to include them in the `app.module.ts`, and even then I am also getting the same error. Any idea how to solve it? I can share more details if needed.

Comment: Use `BsDropdownModule.forRoot` when importing into AppModule.  Use just `BsDropdownModule` when importing into anywhere else.

Answer (score 10):

I was getting the following error in my Angular application based on CoreUI:

```
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[BsDropdownToggleDirective -> BsDropdownDirective]
```

It turned out my issue was that I had a directive misplaced in my template.

I had `dropdownToggle` in a button with no parent `dropdown` directive.

Fixed by switching my button from this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" dropdownToggle>
  Search
</button>
```

. . . to this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
  Search
</button>
```

Comment: This saved my day! I had <ul><li><button ... dropdownToggle>.... and adding the dropdown directive to the parent <li> fixed the problem.

Comment: Hey @JacobBuck, really glad this helped. An upvote would be much apprecaited :)

Answer (score 5):

None of the solutions here worked for me.

The error I was getting:
NullInjectorError: No provider for BsDropdownDirective!

I tried this by chance and it fixed it for me.
Add this to providers in app.module.ts:

...
providers: [BsDropdownConfig],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
...

Comment: Thanks @Aykut. My app needed BsDropdownConfig added to the providers list.

Answer (score 3):

Use BsDropdownModule.forRoot when importing into AppModule. Use just BsDropdownModule when importing anywhere else.

**Why?**

The static forRoot() is intended to be registered with the root injector. This is to ensure that its providers are shared application-wide.

As you can see from the source code, the `forRoot` method returns a module with providers.

https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/src/dropdown/bs-dropdown.module.ts

If you import just the 'BsDropdownModule', it has no providers.  Anywhere else that you want to import the module (like AuthModule), you should import just `BsDropdownModule`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { AuthRoutingModule } from './auth-routing.module';
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { NgxIntlTelInputModule } from 'ngx-intl-tel-input';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AuthRoutingModule,
    BsDropdownModule,
    NgxIntlTelInputModule
  ],
  declarations: [LoginComponent]
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

Comment: Still, I am getting the same error. Even after initializing BsDropdownModule in app.module.ts & using it in the auth.module.ts.

Comment: For the record, I had the same issue when importing ModalModule. Adding `.forRoot()` solved it and saved my day... Thx